# What is wrong with this multi-criteria WHERE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL below doesn't return the correct results. However, when I manually query the State table for 'STATEFP = 6' and insert the PK of that result into a query on the County table (WHERE stateid = 2004 AND countyfp = 45), I get the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM Features
INNER JOIN County ON Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = County.COUNTYFP
INNER JOIN State ON Features.STATE_NUMERIC = State.STATEFP
WHERE (County.COUNTYFP = 45) AND (State.STATEFP = 6)
```

The county returned appears to be the first county that matches. For example,  every state has a county with countyfp = 100. It appears this sql is grabbing the first 100 it finds and with no regard for the state. The state must be taken into account.

What am I doing wrong here?

The features table has a column, CountyId. That column links us to the County table. The County table has a column StateId that links us back to the State table.

Comment: `doesn't return the correct results` what does this mean?

Comment: What are the 'incorrect' results? Your query and the description dont seem to match up. If you're querying `stateid` as a column, that column is not contained in this query for example.

Comment: ...and when you manually query the Features table for:  Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = 45 AND Features.STATE_NUMERIC = 6, what happens?

Comment: What is `code 100`?  You do not mention this in the description of the problem and it is not in your query...

Comment: Is there not a unique identifier in your county table?

Comment: @Abe - The PK in County is Id.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using countyfp as the foreign key instead of the county id?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the join between `FEATURES` and `County` or`FEATURES` and `State` is excluding the results you expect to see?  Try changing it to a `left join` and see if you get the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM Features
LEFT JOIN County ON Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = County.COUNTYFP
LEFT JOIN State ON Features.STATE_NUMERIC = State.STATEFP
WHERE (County.COUNTYFP = 45) AND (State.STATEFP = 6)
```

UPDATE:

Based on your update - `The County table has a column StateId that links us back to the State table.`

Could the issue be that you should be joining `County` and `State` instead of `County` and `FEATURES`?  Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Features
INNER JOIN County ON Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = County.COUNTYFP
INNER JOIN State ON County.STATE_NUMERIC = State.STATEFP
WHERE (County.COUNTYFP = 45) AND (State.STATEFP = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the correct records exist in County and State, but not Features. Does this return any rows?

```
SELECT * FROM Features
WHERE (COUNTY_NUMERIC = 45) AND (STATE_NUMERIC = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like all the rows in `Features` do not have `Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC` and `Features.STATE_NUMERIC` populated properly.

Can you look at the actual data and verify?

If that is the case, the rows that have either value NULL will show up in multiple result sets.

In such cases, cleaning up the data is a much better option than using a `LEFT JOIN`

**EDIT: Column Names**

Are you joining on the wrong columns? Should you be using COUNTYID and STATEID instead of the corresponding FP columns?

```
SELECT * FROM Features
INNER JOIN County ON Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = County.COUNTYID
INNER JOIN State ON Features.STATE_NUMERIC = State.STATEID
WHERE (County.COUNTYFP = 45) AND (State.STATEFP = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I manually query the State table for 'STATEFP = 6' and
>   insert the PK of that result into a query on the County table (WHERE
>   stateid = 2004 AND countyfp = 45)
>   . . . 
>   It appears this sql is grabbing the first 100 it finds and with no
>   regard for the state. The state must be taken into account.

No table def, so this is a guess, but it looks like the query is not not narrowing the counties down by state the way you did manually. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Features
INNER JOIN State ON Features.STATE_NUMERIC = State.STATEFP
INNER JOIN County 
    ON Features.COUNTY_NUMERIC = County.COUNTYFP
    AND State.an_appropriate_column = county.an_appropriate_state_identifier
WHERE (County.COUNTYFP = 45) AND (State.STATEFP = 6)
```